# Text comparison to ignore some newline characters in Python

Tags: python, nlp, difflib

I have a Python script that compares two texts and highlights the differences between them. However, the comparison is being affected by newline characters, causing mismatches for texts with different newline representations. For instance, "arti\ncle" and "article" are being treated as different.

I'm currently using the `difflib`

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```py
import difflib

def compare_texts(old_text, new_text):
    old_lines = old_text.splitlines()
    new_lines = new_text.splitlines()
    
    d = difflib.Differ()
    diff = d.compare(old_lines, new_lines)
    
    added_lines = []
    deleted_lines = []
    
    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('+ '):
            added_lines.append(line[2:])
        elif line.startswith('- '):
            deleted_lines.append(line[2:])
    
    return added_lines, deleted_lines

if __name__ == "__main__":
    old_text = "arti\ncle\nthis is some old text."
    new_text = "article\nthis is some new text."
    
    added_lines, deleted_lines = compare_texts(old_text, new_text)
    
    print("Added lines:")
    print('\n'.join(added_lines))
    
    print("\nDeleted lines:")
    print('\n'.join(deleted_lines))
```

Can someone suggest an effective way to compare texts that will handle newline characters appropriately, ensuring that "arti\ncle" and "article" are treated as the same during the comparison process?

EDIT1:
In fact, lots of "\n" are introduced due to a pdf reading function.
The idea maybe the following: if there is a "\n", we can try to delete it. If, after deleting it, we have a match, then we can consider that they are the same.

So "article" and "arti\ncle" are the same. "article" and "arti\nficial" are not.

I can't remove all "\n" because many of them are still useful.

EDIT2:
knowing the origins of the bugs, we also may try this approach. Some random "\n" have been added due to a pdf reading function, so, we can try to delete some meaningless "\n" first.

Comment: Please explain how "arti\ncle" and "article" are the same? I don't understand it. You could just remove newlines before making the comparison.

Comment: I would say "arti\ncle" should be treated as different compared to "article", because it has two words rather than one, but if you really want to ignore all newline characters, why don't you just remove them before comparing?

Comment: Even after editing your question, it is still unclear why "arti\ncle" and "article" should be the same word. The diff approach takes just both words and compare them. It does not know how the original word in the pdf looked like. You can either try better text extraction approaches from pdf (not that easy) or try to post-process the text extraction output from the pdf (before diff them as already suggested), maybe something like searching for `\n` inside words and replacing them with empty strings. A regular expression might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's  a suggested solution:

- I think you need to do a wordwise diff, not linewise. So replace spaces with linebreaks. (Or use a different diffing method)
- Then check if two consecutively deleted or inserted lines joined together match with a neighboring inserted/deleted line

```py
import difflib

def compare_texts(old_text, new_text):
    old_lines = old_text.splitlines()
    new_lines = new_text.splitlines()
    
    d = difflib.Differ()
    diff = d.compare(old_lines, new_lines)
    
    added_lines = []
    deleted_lines = []
    
    prev = None
    prev_prev = None
    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('+ '):
            added_lines.append(line[2:])
        elif line.startswith('- '):
            deleted_lines.append(line[2:])
        if prev is not None and prev_prev is not None:
            # handle + - - 
            if prev_prev.startswith('+ ') and prev.startswith('- ') and line.startswith('- '):
                joined = prev[2:]  + line[2:]
                if joined == prev_prev[2:]:
                    # can remove diffs as they make up the same word
                    del added_lines[-1]
                    del deleted_lines[-1]
                    del deleted_lines[-1]
            # also handle   - - +    + + -    - + + 
        prev_prev = prev
        prev = line
    
    return added_lines, deleted_lines

if __name__ == "__main__":
    old_text = "arti\ncle\nthis is some old text."
    new_text = "article\nthis is some new text."
    
    added_lines, deleted_lines = compare_texts(old_text.replace(" ", "\n"), new_text.replace(" ", "\n"))
    
    print("Added lines:")
    print('\n'.join(added_lines))
    
    print("\nDeleted lines:")
    print('\n'.join(deleted_lines))
```

You need to handle the other cases, I only implemented `+ - -`.

This solution assumes only one linebreak can be in a word. And all 'good' linebreaks are lost.